# How to set sdtc:valueset attribute to a code or value tag in the xml using java

Tags: java

I am trying to generate QRDA1 using MDHT model and have stuck up with the setting of the `sdtc:valueset` attribute to a code or value tag. The QRDA spec example below shows `sdtc:valueset`:

```
CE code = DatatypesFactory.eINSTANCE.createCE();
code.setCode("247472004");
code.setDisplayName("Hives");
code.setCodeSystem("2.16.840.1.113883.6.96");
code.setCodeSystemName("SNOMED CT");
```

these tags are present in MDHT library but

```
code.setValueSet("{$QDMElementValueSetOID}");
```

is not present in mdht model.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the updated Runtime jars which contains the sdtc:value attribute for code and values set are located at the below link
http://sourceforge.net/projects/oht-modeling/files/Releases/ 
open the link and click on the Runtime which contains the updated jars files.

Comment: I downloaded the latest one. But it is still not working. I cannot find the valueset method.